Filter data according option astro.Build
How to filter data according to the option you choose from a custom select, such as the country and that option is maintained when changeing pages in astro.Build
I have my data in json format and according to the option that the user chooses, the data is filtered without affecting the option when changeing page on the website

Assuming a src/data.json file like:
[
  { "country": "us", "title": "United States" },
  { "country": "gb", "title": "Great Britain" }
]

In src/pages/country/[country].astro you put:
---
import data from '../../data.json'

const { country } = Astro.params
const countryData = data.find(c => c.country === country)
---

<h1>{countryData.title}</h1>

Now you should already be able to access http://localhost:4321/country/us in your browser.
Now for the dropdown, put something like this in src/pages/index.astro:
---
import data from '../data.json'
---
<select name="country" id="select">
  <option disabled selected></option>
  {data.map(c =>
    <option value={c.country}>{c.title}</option>
  )}
</select>

<script>
  const select = document.getElementById('select') as HTMLSelectElement
  select?.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const { value } = select.options[select.selectedIndex]
    document.location.href = '/country/' + value
  })
</script>


If I am working with astro i18, how could I do it, so that it outputs the following http://localhost:4321/br/en
http://localhost:4321/br/es
either
http://localhost:4321/pt/en
http://localhost:4321/pt/es
but sent from the select?

change the document.location.href line to link to the correct thing
